# C++ 14 GCC prefers constructor with std::initializer_list instead of move-constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, initializer-list

I encountered some situation that I cannot explain.
I succeeded to reproduce the problem in a short example:
My class MyObj (originally nlohmann::json) has 2 constructors: move constructor and constructor that receives std::initializer_list.
gcc compiler always prefers the constructor with std::initializer_list while clang prefers move constructor.

The example can be reproduced in online compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/
The compilation line: g++ -std=c++14 -O0 -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
                  clang++ -std=c++14 -O0 -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
class MyUnion
{
public:

    MyUnion(T&& t): _t{std::move(t)} {}

    T _t;
};

struct MyObj
{
    MyObj() : _a(0) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }

    MyObj(MyObj&& r) : _a(std::move(r._a)) { std::cout << "m.ctor" << std::endl; }

    MyObj(const MyObj&& r) : _a(std::move(r._a)) { std::cout << "cm.ctor" << std::endl; }

    MyObj(const MyObj& r) : _a(r._a) { std::cout << "c.ctor" << std::endl; }

    MyObj(std::initializer_list<MyObj> l) : _a(0) { std::cout << "ctr(list)" << std::endl; }

    ~MyObj() { std::cout << "~dtor" << std::endl; }

    int _a;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "MyObj" << std::endl;

    MyObj a{MyObj{}};

    std::cout << "\nMyUnion" << std::endl;

    MyUnion<MyObj> u1{MyObj{}};

    std::cout << "\nfinish" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc output:

```
MyObj
ctor
ctr(list)
~dtor

MyUnion
ctor
m.ctor
ctr(list)
~dtor
~dtor

finish
~dtor
~dtor
```

clang output:

```
MyObj
ctor

MyUnion
ctor
m.ctor
~dtor

finish
~dtor
~dtor
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization says that list-initializing a non-aggregate class object with `{E}` where `E` has the same type will initialize from `E` instead of the normal list-initialization which prefers initializer-list constructors, but draft N4140 very close to C++14 doesn't have this rule. This may have been a change near the finish of the official standard?

Comment: This is the CWG1467/2137 thing again. We should have dups somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

In presence of list-initialization, the initializer-list constructors are chosen in preference to the other constructors (see [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/over.match.list#1.1) for a reference).